# Mapping high-level functions in user-mode dlls to NTDLL.dll

Tags: c++, api, dll, ntdll, nt-native-api

The book [Windows NT/2000 Native API Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578701996) provides a comprehensive documentation (even though outdated) of undocumented (by Microsoft) Native APIs. But I am curious,  is there anyway to find the mappings between low-level functions declared in ntdll.dll and user-mode functions in kernel32.dll, advapi.dll, etc..

For example:

I know the function `CreateFile` maps to `NtCreateFile`. But I don't the exact function in ntdll.dll for `MoveFileWithProgressW` function in kernel32.dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dump exports from user-mode system DLLs using `dumpbin.exe` utility from Windows SDK/Visual Studio and look for forwarded functions:

`dumpbin -exports kernel32.dll | find/I "forwarded" > fwd.txt`

This will create `fwd.txt` file containing a list of forwarded functions, something like this:

```
151   96  EnterCriticalSection (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlEnterCriticalSection)
361  168  GetLastError (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlGetLastWin32Error)
518  205  HeapAlloc (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlAllocateHeap)
524  20B  HeapFree (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlFreeHeap)
528  20F  HeapReAlloc (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlReAllocateHeap)
530  211  HeapSize (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlSizeHeap)
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

NT native API is a lower level API compared to the standard Windows (user mode) API. So there is no one to one correspondence in many cases. I'm guessing that `MoveFileWithProgress` is implemented in user space using lower level open/read/write/close routines.

In other words, if you want to use the Native API, you'll need to re-implement a bunch of convenience functions like `MoveFileWithProgress`.

The Wine project has re-implementations of the Windows API. You can see [their implementation](http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/dlls/kernel32/path.c) to get a taste of how it is done. (Search for "MoveFileWithProgress" in the page)

Comment: Wine uses `wine_nt_to_unix_file_name` followed by `rename`. Better to link to [ReactOS `MoveFileWithProgressW`](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/tags/ReactOS-0.3.16/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/file/move.c?view=markup#l224). If the destination is on the same volume, it uses [`NtSetInformationFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567096) with a [`FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540344) structure.